# How do I interface PHP with htaccess authorization?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I can use "Basic" authorization in an .htaccess file in a directory to control access to it.  But is there some way I can check, if PHP, if the user will have access rights to that directory?

What I want to do, for a given directory, is to create a list of all the directories the user will have access to from PHP.  There are two possible problems that I see - first, if I link directly to an item in that directory (for instance, if I create a link to the directory itself), then .htaccess will prevent unauthorized users from seeing the contents of the directory, but the name will leak.  Unauthorized users should not see the name of the directory if they don't have access!

Second, more serious problem: if I create a link that includes the path and passes it as a parameter to a subsequent PHP invocation, that PHP script can still access the file directly, bypassing the .htaccess password mechanism.   What I need is something like `is_dir` that returns false if the path isn't accessible to the user per .htaccess.

Comment: "Basic" authorization  is great for looking down the admin page of your personal site, but if you need more people with different access go another route

Comment: @Dagon I don't need much beyond basic (typically only one user can access one directory), but PHP doesn't appear to look at .htaccess at all.

Comment: ok i dont see any need to pull php in to it at all, all you want can be done via apache

Comment: @Dagon php is needed, because it's more than simply providing access to the directory.

Comment: You could write a php script to generate all the .htaccess files based on allowed criteria stored in an array (or database depending on how many people you've got), then you'd be able to poll your array for the allowed directories for each user.

Comment: well back to point 1 what you want is more than basic, you should not bother with `"Basic" authorization`

Comment: @Dagon Okay, so what are you suggesting?  Ideally, like .htaccess it would work directly with this filesystem.  All I've got is PHP and Apache, no database or front-end javascript.  Oh, and everything is over SSL, so passwords over the wire are fine.